# How to start an infinity loop on AutoHotKey when reloading the script?

Tags: autohotkey

#### How to start an infinity loop on AutoHotKey when reloading the script?

When my AutoHotKey script is loaded, I want to start a watchdog to monitor when my Octave's Plot window is open. When so, the script will maximize the window.

However this script does not start when I reload it, i.e., does not show the Hi message box.

```
#persistent

SetTitleMatchMode 2
Loop
{
    MsgBox Hi
    WinWait, Figure 1
    WinMaximize
    Sleep 1000
}

Return
```

This is the code before the script:

```
NumpadDot::.
Return

F1::F2
Return

RCtrl::RAlt
Return

#Persistent ; uncomment this line to see the effect
SetTimer, Hello, 1000 ; go to lable hello every second

Hello:
MsgBox Hi
Return


#persistent

SetTitleMatchMode 2
Loop
{
    MsgBox Hi
    WinWait, Figure 1
    WinMaximize
    Sleep 1000
}

Return

;
^+8::
Run "D:\User\Documents\AutoHotKey\MyBatches\kill_macro_player.vbs"
```

References:

1. https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm
2. https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm
3. https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMaximize.htm
4. https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Persistent.htm

Comment: When I tested your script, "Hi" reappeared when I reloaded.   I tested your script by right clicking the AutoHotKey task bar icon and choosing "Edit this script". I replaced my default script with yours and saved it. Then I right clicked the task bar icon again and chose "Reload this script".  "Hi" popped up. When I right clicked the task bar icon and chose "Reload this script" a second time, "Hi" popped up again.

Comment: Do you have any code before or after the code you posted?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for trying. I will add it to the question. My AutoHotKey version is 1.0.48.05

Comment: It looks like your code starts with NumpadDot::. and Return. AHK will autostart any loaded script UP TO the first Return it encounters. As soon as AHK finds a return, all other commands (after that first return) are only executed when triggered (e.g. Hotkey).

Comment: Instead of Sleep, I would use a timer that launches a labeled script (SetTimer [, Label, Period|On|Off|Delete, Priority]). So don't loop, but just launch your labeled script every 1000 ms.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the [@Jim U](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4695439) comment, I find out to fix this adding the script as the first thing on the file:

```
#persistent

SetTitleMatchMode 2
Loop
{
    MsgBox Hi
    WinWait, Figure 1
    WinMaximize
    Sleep 1000
}

Return
```

However, the *AutoHotKey* application started using about **2%** of my CPU's, instead of **0.00%** as before these lines within the script. Then I replaced the `WinWait, Figure 1` by only `WinMaximize Figure 1` and the *AutoHotKey* application started using about **0.08%** of my CPU's processing power, which is much better.

```
#persistent

SetTitleMatchMode 1
Loop
{
    WinMaximize Figure 1
    Sleep 1000
}

Return
```

As for [@Robert Ilbrink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989697) comment:

> It looks like your code starts with NumpadDot::. and Return. AHK will autostart any loaded script UP TO the first Return it encounters. As soon as AHK finds a return, all other commands (after that first return) are only executed when triggered (e.g. Hotkey).
>
> Instead of Sleep, I would use a timer that launches a labeled script (SetTimer [, Label, Period|On|Off|Delete, Priority]). So don't loop, but just launch your labeled script every 1000 ms.

```
#persistent

SetTimer, check_for_windows, 1000
SetTitleMatchMode 1

check_for_windows:
{
    ; MsgBox, Hello
    WinMaximize Figure 1
}

Return
```

However both ways with `Sleep` or `SetTimer` the CPU use kept the same way, but with `SetTimer` it seems to be consuming around **0.09%** instead of **0.08%** of my CPU use.

References:

1. https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm
2. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/40986-what-is-wintext/
3. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/63955-can-you-please-give-a-simple-example-of-persistent/

---

## General Handler

I created a more general scrip handler, now it can be setup for more programs. Here in I commented the `WinWait` commands due they eat much CPU as explained above.

```
; Declare it to be alive all the time.
#persistent

; Create the initial task to start working.
SetTimer, check_for_sublime_settings_window, 1000
SetTimer, check_for_octave_graphics_window, 1000

; Set to window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.
SetTitleMatchMode 1

; Stop the initial configuration setup, i.e., this execution flow.
Return

check_for_sublime_settings_window:
{
    ; Here we wait until the windows is activated and only then to maximize it.
    ;WinWait, Preferences.sublime-settings

    ; If we do not wait for it, it will bring the windows up every time we minimize it.
    WinMaximize, Preferences.sublime-settings
    
    ; Set to wait for the next time the windows open within 1 seconds delay.
    SetTimer, check_for_sublime_settings_window, 1000
}
; To stop this execution flow
Return


check_for_octave_graphics_window:
{
    ;WinWait, Figure 1
    WinMaximize, Figure 1
    SetTimer, check_for_octave_graphics_window, 1000
}
Return
```